# Applescript: deselect current selection in iTunes

Tags: applescript, itunes, unselect, deselect

I want to unselect the current selection in iTunes using Applescript. Is that possible?

This is what I do

1. Manually select several tracks in iTunes.
2. Launch the script (actually a Automator service) that stores the selection in a list.
3. Now I want to display the info window of the first track in the selection.

Currently I do this buy sending a key combo to iTunes. The problem is that when I have several tracks selected the info window iTunes opens are for all selected tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set sel to (get selection)
    # ... do something with sel ...
    reveal (get item 1 of sel)
end tell
```